# Understanding register usage in the switch condition

Tags: c, assembly, x86, switch-statement, cpu-registers

I have a switch-condition code in C and assembly code.
But it seems very arbitrary to me what to set, edx or eax or ecx?

How do I tell the difference between edx, epx, ecx, ebp? Even the textbook does not give me the sufficient explanation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Enumerated type creates set of constants
// numbered 0 and upward
typedef enum {MODE_A, MODE_B, MODE_C, MODE_D, MODE_E} mode_t;

int switchmode(int *p1, int *p2, mode_t action)
{
  int result = 0;
  switch(action) {
    case MODE_A:
      result = *p1;
      *p1 = *p2;
      break;
    case MODE_B:
      *p2 += *p1;
      result = *p2;
      break;
    case MODE_C:
      *p2 = 15;
      result = *p1;
      break;
    case MODE_D:
      *p2 = *p1;
      /* Fall Through */
    case MODE_E:
      result = 17;
      break;
    default:
      result = -1;
  }
  return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  int num1 = 10;
  int num2 = 20;

  printf("MODE_A: %d \n", switchmode(&num1, &num2, MODE_A)); // 10
  printf("MODE_B: %d \n", switchmode(&num1, &num2, MODE_B)); // 40
  printf("MODE_C: %d \n", switchmode(&num1, &num2, MODE_C)); // 20
  printf("MODE_D: %d \n", switchmode(&num1, &num2, MODE_D)); // 17
  printf("MODE_E: %d \n", switchmode(&num1, &num2, MODE_E)); // 17
  printf("NULL: %d \n", switchmode(&num1, &num2, (mode_t) NULL)); // 20
    return 0;
}
```

And the assembly code is

```
Arguments:  p1      at %ebp+8
            p2      at %ebp+12
            action  at %ebp+16

Register: result in %edx (initialized to -1)

.L17: // MODE_E
  movl $17, %edx
  jmp .L19
.L13: // MODE_A
  movl 8(%ebp), %eax
  movl (%eax), %edx
  movl 12(%ebp), %ecx
  movl (%ecx), %eax
  movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
  movl %eax, (%ecx)
  jmp .L19
.L14: // MODE_B
  movl 12(%ebp), %edx
  movl (%edx), %eax
  movl %eax, %edx
  movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
  addl (%ecx), %edx
  movl 12(%ebp), %eax
  movl %edx, (%eax)
  jmp .L19
.L15: // MODE_C
  movl 12(%ebp), %edx
  movl $15, (%edx)
  movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
  movl (%ecx), %edx
  jmp .L19
.L16: // MODE_D
  movl 8(%ebp), %edx
  movl (%edx), %eax
  movl 12(%ebp), %ecx
  movl %eax, (%ecx)
  movl $17, %edx
.L19: // default
  movl %edx, %eax // set return value
```

My question is

How do I know what is eax? Is it one of the arguments?
If so, how do I know which is the eax and ecx and which is edx?

Comment: why do you care? Textbook won't help. You need to reverse the compiler.

Comment: if you know what ebp is why don't you know eax if it's often appears first in the register list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most assembly code, whatever is in %eax is the value returned from the function. That is why in the .L19 block whatever was in %edx is moved into %eax. Looking back, wherever you set `result` to something, the code moves that value into %edx so that when the code jumps to .L19 the value will be placed in %eax by default.
This looks like a 32-bit system, so it has 8 general-purpose registers:

- %ebx, %ecx, %edx, %esi, and %edi are registers that mostly store whatever data is necessary for them to hold at any given time.
- %eax holds the return value for a function, e.g. the function that called it will be looking in %eax for that function's return value before it changes %eax.
- %ebp and %esp are special registers that essentially manage and allocate space on the stack for various function calls.

To see where your arguments are being placed, look at where that data is being referenced in the code. For example, at .L13, the program places %ebp+8 (which is p1) into %eax, then places the value at that address (*p1) into %edx. So, %edx now holds the value pointed to by p1.
The registers DO NOT hold the arguments to the function. Don't think that %edx contains one of the arguments to `switchmode()` by default. Arguments are always placed on the stack.