# Converting a snippit of x86 Assembly Code into C

Tags: c, assembly, x86

this is a piece of an assignment on assembly code. I'm not sure if I'm quite grasping it. This is one of 5 switch statements where I must write the equivalent C code. Is it just me not understanding what is going on here, or is there a lot of unnecessary code?

Parameter p1 is stored at %ebp+8, Parameter p2 is at %ebp+12. The result is initialized to -1 and stored in %edx. .L19: sets the return value.

When I trace it my understanding is that the p1 is placed into %eax. Then the address pointed to by %eax (which is p1's value) is placed into %edx. Then the last 4 lines are unnecessary because the return register is not touched the rest of the switch.

```
    movl     8(%ebp), %eax
    movl     (%eax), %edx
    movl     12(%ebp), ecx
    movl     (%ecx), %eax
    movl     8(%ebp), %ecx
    movl     %eax, (%ecx)
    jmp      .L19
```

Is my book just trying to be tricky or am I completely missing the mark here? Thanks.

Comment: *p1 => %edx;  *p1=(*p2) ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the result stored in `%edx`?  The calling conventions I'm familiar with in x86 all use `%eax` as the return value for integer/pointer values.

I don't think you're really far off:

```
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
movl    (%eax), %edx
```

This is about like:

```
int value = *p1;
```

Then:

```
movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
movl    (%ecx), %eax
```

Which looks about like:

```
int value2 = *p2;
```

Then finally:

```
movl    8(%ebp), %ecx)
movl    %eax, (%ecx)
jmp     .L19
```

Which amounts to:

```
*p1 = value2;
break;
```

Summary:

```
int value = *p1;
int value2 = *p2;
*p1 = value2
break;
```

Heh.  This must be a common homework question or an online MOOC or something.  Check it out: [C, Assembly : understanding the switch condition, edx eax ecx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624330/c-assembly-understanding-the-switch-condition-edx-eax-ecx?rq=1)

Taken from this one, it looks like you're talking about `MODE_A`:

```
int switchmode(int *p1, int *p2, mode_t action)
{
  int result = 0;
  switch(action) {
    case MODE_A:
      result = *p1;
      *p1 = *p2;
      break;
    case MODE_B:
      *p2 += *p1;
      result = *p2;
      break;
    case MODE_C:
      *p2 = 15;
      result = *p1;
      break;
    case MODE_D:
      *p2 = *p1;
      /* Fall Through */
    case MODE_E:
      result = 17;
      break;
    default:
      result = -1;
  }
  return result;
}
```

As an aside, the result is transferred to `%eax` at the end, just like one would expect.

Comment: I may have described this slightly incorrectly. This is a case in the switch. There are 4 more cases like it that all have code that doesn't seem useful at all to me. Additionally %edx is the result value, not the return. However, .19: has the line:  movl %edx, %eax.  So I still am failing to see the use of the last lines of code. Thanks.

Comment: Setting a pointer is definitely "a use".  Exactly what, I'm not sure without taking the time to read the rest of the code (such as I linked), but it's definitely not nothing.